# How to make 100% height inside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<div id="a">
    <div style="background-color: green;">content above blue div</div>
    <div id="b">I want this as height as the #a<br /> and if bigger, I want to get<br /> scrollbars</div>
</div>

#a
{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#b
{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/29ao3oLq/1/

the content in blue div can be longer, and I want to be as height as yellow div now. But I cant know the height because there is the green div, with unknown height.

Comment: Is the height for `#a` (100px) a fixed value?  what happens is the height of the green div and the blue div add up to more than 100px, do you expect a scroll bar?

Comment: What defines the height of the green bar? Is it dynamic content with various heights?

Comment: @Mouser yea that is dynamic too. It might doesnt even gets shown

Comment: Hmms bummer, else we could've used the `calc` function in CSS, @MarcAudet's answer is nice, but doing it without table (even in css) would be nicer.

Answer (score 3):

This css, using *flexbox* should do it.

```
#a
{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start; /* align items in Main Axis */
    align-items: stretch; /* align items in Cross Axis */
    align-content: stretch; /* Extra space in Cross Axis */    

}

#c
{
    background-color: green;

}

#b
{
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: auto;
    flex: 1;
}
```

Little adaptation to the HTML:

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="c" >content above blue div</div>
    <div id="b">I want this as height as the #a<br /> and if bigger, I want to get<br /> scrollbars<br /> scrollbars<br /> scrollbars<br /> scrollbars<br /> scrollbars<br /> scrollbars<br /> scrollbars</div>
</div>
```

Read more: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

See it: http://jsfiddle.net/29ao3oLq/3/

Cheers!

Comment: What I like about your answer is that it does not need extra mark-up.  The only (temporary) limitation is that flex is not fully supported, but that may not be a problem for the OP.

Comment: @MarcAudet Yes I would've used tables a year ago. Coming up with almost the same solution. Nowadays if I know the height of a footer or header I use `calc`. Brilliant function. Flexbox is the new kid in town and it's nice functionality. I'm trying to master it.

Comment: The OP's green div does not have a specified height, so the `calc` function would not work in this case, most unfortunate.  Time for me to lean about the flexbox! All the best!

Answer (score 2):

If you add a couple of wrapper elements, you can get realize this layout using CSS tables.

You may need to modify this if your content gets very long (causes scroll bars to appear).

```css
#a {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: table;
}
#b {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
}
#a div.row {
  display: table-row;
}
#a div.row div {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div class="row r1">
    <div style="background-color: green;">content above blue div<br>more stuff</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row r2">
    <div id="b">I want this as height as the #a
      <br />and if bigger, I want to get
      <br />scrollbars</div>
  </div>
</div>
```